# Excel VBA Multiselect and Set Workbooks as Variables

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, multi-select

Previously I had a block of code that would use GetOpenFilename for a single file, set variables, ask if you wanted to select another file(Y/N), execute more code to open 2nd file, etc. If user selected 'NO' at any point, it would skip remaining code.

What I am attempting to do is have a macro stored within a workbook open up to 3 files. It then needs to make each workbook it's own variable because it needs to find a string in each of the workbooks before passing those variables onto another Module. I can't figure how for the code to Set each workbook. Appreciate any help.

```
Dim files As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim WBtemp1 As Workbook
Dim WBtemp2 As Workbook
Dim WBtemp3 As Workbook
Dim RF As String

    files = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel workbooks (*.xls*),*.xls*", Title:="Please select up to 3 Files", MultiSelect:=True)

    If Not IsArray(files) Then Exit Sub

    If UBound(files) < 3 Then
        MsgBox "You have selected more than 3 files."

    End If



    For i = 1 To UBound(files)

    Workbooks.Open files(i)

    Next

    Set WBtemp1 = Workbooks(1)
    Set WBtemp2 = Workbooks(2)
    Set WBtemp3 = Workbooks(3)


    RF = WBtemp1.Worksheets(1).Range("V3")
    RF1 = Mid(RF, 12, 8)
    RF = WBtemp2.Worksheets(1).Range("V3")
    RF2 = Mid(RF, 12, 8)
    RF = WBtemp3.Worksheets(1).Range("V3")
    RF3 = Mid(RF, 12, 8)



        Call Macro2(WBtemp1, WBtemp2, WBtemp3, RF1, RF2, RF3)
```

Answer (score 1):

To set your variables to point to the 3 selected workbooks, you need to use the values stored in the `files` array and extract the filename without the folder path and then use it to refer to the workbook:

```
Dim filenames(1 To 3) As String
For i = 1 To 3
    filenames(i) = Right(files(i), Len(files(i)) - InStrRev(files(i), "\"))
Next i
Dim WBtemp1, WBtemp2, WBtemp3

Set WBtemp1 = Workbooks(filenames(1))
Set WBtemp2 = Workbooks(filenames(2))
Set WBtemp3 = Workbooks(filenames(3))
```

Or instead, even better, you can assign each workbook to a variable as you open then by doing:

```
Set WBtemp1 = Workbooks.Open(files(1))
Set WBtemp2 = Workbooks.Open(files(2))
Set WBtemp3 = Workbooks.Open(files(3))
```

Comment: So that triggers a 'Subscript out of range' on the 
    Set WBtemp1 = Workbooks(files(1))
whether it opens 1 file or multiple.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I found too. However,  that causing excel to reopen the workbooks?

Comment: You would have to replace the lines where you open the workbook by those where you assign it to variable to avoid opening the files twice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that I think you can actually use. It shows how to create and handle the array of workbooks and creates a similar array for Rf. I have added a `Macro2` sub which takes the arrays as argument as well as a function which takes only one of the array members (a Sub would be called in the same manner).

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectFiles()

    Dim Files As Variant
    Dim WbTempl() As Workbook
    Dim Tmp As String
    Dim Rf() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Files = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel workbooks (*.xls*),*.xls*", _
                                        Title:="Please select up to 3 Files", _
                                        MultiSelect:=True)

    If IsArray(Files) Then                  ' avoid jumps: let the code flow
        For i = 1 To UBound(Files)
            If i > 3 Then
                MsgBox "You selected " & UBound(Files) & " files." & vbCr & _
                       "Only the first 3 will be processed.", _
                       vbInformation, "Too many files selected"
                ReDim Preserve Files(1 To 3)
                Exit For
            Else
                ReDim Preserve WbTempl(1 To i)
            End If
            Set WbTempl(i) = Workbooks.Open(Files(i))
        Next i

        ReDim Rf(1 To UBound(WbTempl))
        For i = 1 To UBound(WbTempl)
            Tmp = WbTempl(i).Worksheets(1).Range("V3").Value
            If Len(Tmp) < 20 Then
                Tmp = String(20, "R")
            End If
            Rf(i) = Mid(Tmp, 12, 8)
            If IsTemplate(WbTempl(i), Rf(i)) = True Then
                Tmp = " "
            Else
                Tmp = " not "
            End If
            MsgBox WbTempl(i).Name & " is" & Tmp & "a template", vbInformation
        Next i

        ' using meaningful names isn't a useless exercise
        ' using nondescript names will cost you much more time eventually
        Macro2 WbTempl, Rf
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Macro2(Wb() As Workbook, _
                   Rf() As String)

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To UBound(Wb)
        Debug.Print Rf(i), Wb(i).Name
    Next i
End Sub

Private Function IsTemplate(Wb As Workbook, _
                           ByVal Rf As String) As Boolean

    Debug.Print "Here is Function 'IsTemplate'. Current Rf = "; Rf
    IsTemplate = (Wb.FileFormat = xlTemplate)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Amended to this. Added an `On Error Resume Next` in the module.

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim MyFiles As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim WBtemp1 As Workbook
Dim WBtemp2 As Workbook
Dim WBtemp3 As Workbook

    MyFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel workbooks(*.xls*),*.xls*", Title:="Please select up to 3 Files", MultiSelect:=True)

    If Not IsArray(MyFiles) Then Exit Sub

    If UBound(MyFiles) > 3 Then
        MsgBox "You have selected more than 3 files."

    End If

    For i = 1 To UBound(MyFiles)

    Workbooks.Open MyFiles(i)

    Next i


    Set WBtemp1 = Workbooks.Open(MyFiles(1))

    If UBound(MyFiles) < 2 Then GoTo Sng Else GoTo Mult

Mult:
    Set WBtemp2 = Workbooks.Open(MyFiles(2))
    Set WBtemp3 = Workbooks.Open(MyFiles(3))

        RF = WBtemp1.Worksheets(1).Range("V3")
        RF1 = Mid(RF, 12, 8)

        RF = WBtemp2.Worksheets(1).Range("V3")
        RF2 = Mid(RF, 12, 8)

        RF = WBtemp3.Worksheets(1).Range("V3")
        RF3 = Mid(RF, 12, 8)

Sng:
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook


        Call Macro2(WBtemp1, WBtemp2, WBtemp3, RF1, RF2, RF3)
```